# Use of both adjective and verb in place of object clauses

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, verbs, parallelism

I've been trying to assemble this sentence, but something feels wrong with every option I've come up with.

> This has made me frustrated and lack motivation to go on this way.

or:

> This has made me frustrated and lacked of motivation to go on this way.

or:

> This has made me frustrated and made me lack motivation to go on this way.

How would you say it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try either of these:

> This has made me frustrated and lacking of motivation to go on this way.

or

> This has frustrated me and drained my motivation to go on this way.

Comment: makes sense, thx!

Comment: _Lacking motivation_ is also grammatical, and _Lacking in motivation_ feels better than _Lacking of motivation_ to me (American).

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of brevity and consistency within the sentence, consider:

> This has made me frustrated and unmotivated to go on this way.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say one of the following:

> This has frustrated me, so I have no motivation to go on this way.

or

> This has frustrated me, so I'm {no longer / not} motivated to go on this way.

or

> Because this has frustrated me, I have no motivation to go on this way.

*I lack motivation* is just a tad pretentious. One normally says *I'm not {motivated to learn / interested in learning} how to operate my new Google Nexus 7 tablet, so I gave it to my son for Christmas* [True fact]. It's usually something one says about somebody else: *He lacks the necessary motivation to learn anything that requires an hour of daily practice*.